# Saving a list into xlsx - python

Tags: python, pandas

I am fairly new to python, and I am learning pandas.

I am trying to save a list into an excel file to have it all in one (two) columns with some index identifying records (like from each list these strings are comming) - I tried few things but i'm stuck here.
Desirable output on the last screen I showed - any tips / help for newbie here?
Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: *starting* with pandas? :\ :)

Comment: why not! :) I just finished some basic Python course - but since I want to use python only to automate "boring" stuff - as one book said - I jumped right into pandas to automate some tasks I might have - i am trying to make some "exercise" that comes to my head

Comment: Fair enough :) Good luck - and SO is a great community to start with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(data).stack().droplevel(1)
0    A
0    B
0    C
1    D
1    E
1    F
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly :)